# How change specific values from different columns in a same row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a prices time-series from 2013 to 2020 which the columns I'm interested about are:
'date': date of when the data was collected
'max': maximum price commercialized that day
'mcom': most common price commercialized that day
'min': minimum price commercialized that day.

In exploratory analysis I realized that in some dates the 'mcom' are higher than 'max' and I discovered that in these specific rows the 'mcom' values should be the 'max' values and vice versa.

I used the loc function as bellow to see the dates where this happen:

```
dfc.loc[dfc['mcom'] > dfc['max']]
```

and it returned me:

```
    data    dia mes ano wday    prod    und proc    tipo    min mcom    max merc    julian  mm
date                                                            
2016-10-04 12:00:00 04/10/2016  4   10  2016    nan Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1372.416667 1.11
2016-10-05 12:00:00 05/10/2016  5   10  2016    quarta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1373.416667 1.11
2016-10-06 12:00:00 06/10/2016  6   10  2016    quinta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1374.416667 1.11
2016-10-07 12:00:00 07/10/2016  7   10  2016    sexta   Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1375.416667 1.11
2016-10-10 12:00:00 10/10/2016  10  10  2016    segunda Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1378.416667 1.11
2016-10-11 12:00:00 11/10/2016  11  10  2016    nan Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1379.416667 1.11
2016-10-13 12:00:00 13/10/2016  13  10  2016    quinta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1381.416667 1.11
2016-10-14 12:00:00 14/10/2016  14  10  2016    sexta   Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1382.416667 1.11
2016-10-17 12:00:00 17/10/2016  17  10  2016    segunda Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1385.416667 1.11
2016-10-18 12:00:00 18/10/2016  18  10  2016    nan Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1386.416667 1.11
2016-10-19 12:00:00 19/10/2016  19  10  2016    quarta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    4.89    8.85    6.00    Est 1387.416667 1.11
2017-10-03 12:00:00 03/10/2017  3   10  2017    nan Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    6.80    6.90    6.89    Est 1736.416667 0.09
2017-10-04 12:00:00 04/10/2017  4   10  2017    quarta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    6.80    6.90    6.89    Est 1737.416667 0.09
2017-10-05 12:00:00 05/10/2017  5   10  2017    quinta  Peixe de agua salgada   Kg  nan Sardinha    6.80    6.90    6.89    Est 1738.416667 0.09
```

How can I put the 'mcom' values in where the 'max' values are and vice versa?

Comment: Are you only wanting to switch the values when `dfc.loc[dfc['mcom'] > dfc['max']]` is true?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try

```py
m = dfc['mcom'] > dfc['max']

dfc.loc[m, 'mcom'], dfc.loc[m, 'max'] = dfc.loc[m, 'max'], dfc.loc[m, 'mcom']
# or
dfc.loc[m, ['max', 'mcom']] = dfc.loc[m, ['mcom', 'max']].values
```

```
print(dfc)

    min  mcom   max
0  4.89   6.0  8.85
1  4.89   6.0  8.85
2  4.89   6.0  8.85
```